# Make options of Material-ui autocomplete component clickable links?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, autocomplete, material-ui

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function FreeSolo(props) {
  const [vendors, setVendors] = React.useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
  const nameRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    sendDataToParent();
  }, [value]);

  const sendDataToParent = async () => {
    await props.parentFunction(value);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{}}>
      <Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        id="free-solo-2-demo"
        options={props.vendorData.map((option) => option.name)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            value={value}
            required
            inputRef={nameRef}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setValue(e.target.value);
              sendDataToParent();
            }}
            label="Vendor Name"
            margin="normal"
            variant="standard"
            InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, type: "search" }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to do it using renderOption but could not get it working. I need to have the options to be clickable links so that whenever user selects of the options, he is redirected to the link.

EDIT: Solved using renderOption

```
renderOption={(option) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <span
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => {
                window.location.href = `/allvendors/${option.id}`;
              }}
            >
              {option.name} - Click to visit the Vendor
            </span>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the options clickable links, you can redirect to the link using the `onChange` prop of the `Autocomplete` component.

I'm assuming each option in your `vendorData` has a `name` and also a `link`  e.g.

```
{
  name: "Google",
  link: "https://www.google.com"
}
```

To be able to access the link from this object in the `Autocomplete` component's `onChange`, you'll need to change the `options` map function to return the whole `option`. After this change, if you try to click to open the dropdown, it will throw an error because the option label needs to be a `string` (e.g. the option name) and not an object (e.g. option). So, we need to add the `getOptionLabel` prop and return the `option.name`.

Finally, in the `onChange` function, we set the `window.location.href` equal to the `option.link`, which changes the current page's URL to the link and directs the user to that link.

```
<div style={{}}>
  <Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    id="free-solo-2-demo"
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    options={props.vendorData.map((option) => option)}
    onChange={(event: any, option: any) => {
      window.location.href = option.link;
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        value={value}
        required
        inputRef={nameRef}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
          sendDataToParent();
        }}
        label="Vendor Name"
        margin="normal"
        variant="standard"
        InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, type: "search" }}
      />
    )}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the clarification about the getOptionLabel and options.